# highlighting current list-item in navigation bar

Tags: css

I am including header file in each of my web page for navigation bar, how can I show the current page activated/highlighted?

```
<div id="header"><div  id="nav">
            <ul id="menu">
            <?php
$CurrentPage = $path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__,PATHINFO_FILENAME); // u will get the current page name "index.php", home.php etc..
?>
                <?php
                if(!logged_in())
                {
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Home') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #CCFFFF;\" ><a href=\"index.php\">Home</a></li>";
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                if(logged_in())
                {
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Home') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #CCFFFF;\" ><a href=\"index.php\">Home</a></li>";
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Contact Us') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #66FFFF;\"><a href=\"contact.php\">Contact Us</a></li>";

                ?>
            </ul>
            </div></div>
```

How can I include this CSS for `id="current"`

```
#header #nav ul li#current a {  
    background: transparent url(../images/current.gif) repeat-x left bottom;    
    color: #222;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
#nav #menu #current a
```

instead of

```
#header #nav ul li#current a
```

Maybe you should add `#header` as well but i did not see any #header in the code above.

```
<style>
#header #nav #menu #current a {  
    background: transparent url(../images/current.gif) repeat-x left bottom;    
    color: #222;    
}
</style>


    <div id="header"><div  id="nav">
            <ul id="menu">
            <?php
$CurrentPage = $path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__,PATHINFO_FILENAME); // u will get the current page name "index.php", home.php etc..
?>
                <?php
                if(!logged_in())
                {
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Home') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #CCFFFF;\" ><a href=\"index.php\">Home</a></li>";
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                if(logged_in())
                {
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Home') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #CCFFFF;\" ><a href=\"index.php\">Home</a></li>";
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                echo "<li id=\"<?php echo ($CurrentPage=='Contact Us') ? 'current' : ''?>\" style=\"background-color: #66FFFF;\"><a href=\"contact.php\">Contact Us</a></li>";

                ?>
            </ul>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: You can trim it to `#current a`.

Comment: and when raj needs a different highlighting somewhere else with `#current a`?

Comment: I tried `#header #nav #menu #current a` its not highlighting current page as per css

Comment: @Jurgo Let's assume he doesn't have a particular id more than once on a page.

Comment: @raj, is #header present? did you try `#current a` as Pavlo suggested?

Comment: @raj, next time create a Fiddle by yourself, OR post generated HTML / CSS, not php code. I created one for you, and changed the ugly #222 to a 'red' highlighting, just as a test. As you can see, Jurgo solution works. http://jsfiddle.net/RmZNH/

Comment: @Jurgo i edited #header as i have it in my code ,i tried both are note working in my code

Comment: @raj how do you include the css?

Comment: I have included `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />` in `header.php`,and in this i have 1 line of code `@import url("FreshPick.css");` and in `FreshPick.css` i have given css code

Comment: and the FreshPick.css is loaded succesfully?

Comment: yes FreshPick.css getting loaded successfully,and i have even tried adding style part in haeder.php,where i have mistake?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22371/discussion-between-raj-and-jurgo)